# Logging issue in graphics terminal in Ubuntu 20.04 after timeshift setup

Tags: 20.04, backup, btrfs, timeshift

I installed timeshift btrfs type in my Dell laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 for btrfs. After reboot, I see login is not possible in graphics console and so pressing CTRL-ALT-F2 I came to text console and loging was possible. However, after the login, I see that /home and /opt partitions are missing which are listed in /etc/fstab and `pwd` shows directory `/`. I could see the partitions using `sudo fdisk -l` command. The command `lsblk` was showing for partuuid for those two partitions which was not matching with the uuid mentioned with that at /etc/fstab. The command `sudo btrfs subvol list \` shows /home and and /opt as level 5 with IDs and backup entries.

This means those two partitions with timeshifted backups exist and btrfs can see.

I visited [snapshots with timeshift](https://mutschler.eu/linux/install-guides/ubuntu-btrfs-raid1/), [timeshift github](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen), [btrfs](https://linuxhint.com/install-and-use-btrfs-on-ubuntu-lts/),[askUbuntu on timeshift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324265/timeshift-unanswered-questions) and more.

I tried to find solutions and now I am asking question. I request to kindly advice me on the procedure to fix the issue so that system can have proper mount instead of just stamping as *repeated question* with any successful solution.

Comment: Can you mount the partitions manually?

Comment: Thanks. No, I cannot mount. I can see partitions in ```fdisk```, I can see partitions with backups using ```btrfs subvol``` command as reported in question.

Comment: Perhaps you cold show your `/etc/fstab` and output/errors from `lsblk`, `btrfs`, and `mount` commands.