# Will timeshift backup all the files in "/" (include /etc, /bin, /dev, /boot ...)?

Tags: backup, timeshift

I want to use timeshift to make backups. But I only see it make backup for /usr, /var. So I want to know whether it will make backup for /boot, /etc,...

If I broke the files under /etc, will the timeshift be able to help me fix it?

Also I remember there was a time I use timeshift to restore files, and when I reboot I found there are two "grub", not knowing why.

Can someone explain my Questions？ I'm a new hand Ubuntu user.

Answer (score 1):

TimeShift does not make backups. It makes snapshots of your system. You can specify a schedule when TimeShift will create snapshots. It can then restore your system to the state it was in when the chosen snapshot was created. I’ve done this and it works well.

By default TimeShift will include /boot and /etc but it is possible to exclude them. You can check what is specified in the snapshot in terms of exclusions using the GUI wizard. After you have run the snapshot you can get an idea of what is included by looking in your snapshot location at /timeshift

You might find my answer here helpful [Timeshift unanswered questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324265/timeshift-unanswered-questions/1324399#1324399)